# Database column not concatenating strings SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using the following to update a SQLite database...

```
using (SQLiteCommand updateSQL = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE SOULS SET CapturableStage = CapturableStage || @info WHERE Name LIKE @character AND Rarity = @rarity", con))

updateSQL.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@character", "%"+c.Value.Name+ "%"));
updateSQL.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@rarity", c.Value.Rarity));
updateSQL.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@info", s.Value.Name + ","));
```

The problem is that the `CapturableStage` column isn't being concatenated. In fact nothing is being updated at all.

If I run this without the concatenation part the update works fine..

```
using (SQLiteCommand updateSQL = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE SOULS SET CapturableStage = @info WHERE Name LIKE @character AND Rarity = @rarity", con))
```

...accept that obviously the `CapturableStage` isn't concatenated.

Why isn't `CapturableStage ||` working here?

Comment: I've never seen that syntax used in Android. Could you please show a [mcve]?

Comment: @cricket_007 Apoligies, I realised I had put CapturableStage || CapturableInfo instead of CapturableStage || CapturableStage. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Not really. I was more asking about the `@info`, for example. Is info a String variable or a column in the table?

Comment: @cricket_007 The edit may help you

Comment: Looks like the issue is to do with some of the rows being NULL. Easy fix.

Comment: Cool. I was going to suggest using the `update` method of the SqliteOpenHelper

Comment: @cricket_007 That's just a [parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam).